# C++ typedef typename classname::template

Tags: c++, templates

I am not able to parse the meaning of the following line of code:

```
typedef typename Allocator::template rebind<Mapped>::other mapped_type_allocator;
```

This is the code for allocator rebinding (line 63 of 
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-api-4.5/a00756_source.html)

How is this different from the following?

```
typedef typename Allocator::rebind<Mapped>::other mapped_type_allocator;
```

Answer (score 10):

Here I show the grouping of this declaration on separate lines:

```
typedef                                                    mapped_type_allocator;
        typename Allocator::                       ::other 
                            template rebind<Mapped>
```

The keywords `typename` and `template` have spaces after them which may have confused you.  For the reason those two keywords were used, see [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords) .

Comment: I like the visual representation. +1

Answer (score 9):

```
typedef typename Allocator::template rebind<Mapped>::other mapped_type_allocator;
```

This is a [templated typedef](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/079.htm) - it establishes `mapped_type_allocator` as an alias for a template.

---

```
typedef typename Allocator::rebind<Mapped>::other mapped_type_allocator;
```

This is a typedef for a type. To compile OK, the `Mapped` would need to be defined/known.

---

The `Allocator::rebind<typename X>::other` (as a concept) is expected to define a *template*, not a type.