# Aliasing the member template typedef with using makes compiler think it is not a class template

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

Eventually I need to filter a typelist (`brigand::list` - defined in brigand meta-programming library). But to start:

I have a settings class that holds a type list:

```
   template<typename TComponentList>
  class Settings {

    // this is an integral_constant holding bool
    template<typename TList, typename T>
    using ContainsFilter = brigand::found<TList, std::is_same<T, brigand::_1>>;

    // is the type present in component list?
       template<typename T>
    using IsComponentFilter = ContainsFilter<TComponentList, T>;
}
```

The brigand library offers a `filter` "function", but to pass my filter there i need to wrap it using `brigand::bind`. Here's an example of that:

```
using ls = brigand::list<TagA, SignatureA, ComponentB>;

// binds the template parameter - passes it to my filter
using wrapped = brigand::bind<TestSettings::IsComponentFilter, brigand::_1>;

// a list holding only ComponentB
using filtered = brigand::filter<ls, wrapped>;
```

The last step - which i cannot overcome, is to put the filtering inside a class, depending on a template param:

```
   template <class TSettings>
    struct FilteringClass
    {
        // problem line
        using wrapped = brigand::bind<TSettings::IsComponentFilter, brigand::_1>;

        // template<typename TSignature>
        // using SignatureComponents = brigand::filter<TSignature, wrapped>;
    };
```

When compiling the problem line i first get an error that i need to use typename keyword before `TSettings`:

```
to refer to a type member of a template parameter, use 'typename TSettings::
```

That sounds exactly like what i want!
 I guess it is needed to explicitly tell compiler to treat `TSettings` as a type? However when i add it, i get this error from inside `brigand's` bind function:

```
error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template<template<class ...> class<template-parameter-1-1>, class ...> struct brigand::bind'
     using wrapped = brigand::bind<TSettings, brigand::_1>;
 note:   expected a class template, got '(TSettings:: IsComponentFilter < <expression error>)'
```

Comment: You probably want: `template <template <typename> class TSettings> struct FilteringClass`. first argument of bind seems to be a template instead of a type.

Comment: I'm guessing Jarod has the answer. But we would have a better hint if you could show an example usage of `FilteringClass` (with whatever you provide as a template argument also declared).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, i found what i was missing, albeit almost randomly
To add that another alias correctly i needed to add `::template`, like that:

```
template<typename T>
using wrapped = brigand::bind<typename TSettings::template IsComponentFilter, brigand::_1>;
```

I guess without it the fact that original alias was templated was somehow lost to the compiler.

The meaning of the keyword is nicely explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40035282/c-typedef-typename-classnametemplate/40035372).